# How to start Bluetooth connect thread when pressed button

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I am struggling to get my connect thread started when pressed "connect" button on my activity. I have tried to google the right answer for this but I have got very confused about what method to implement to get it work. I'm not sure if it's a Handler or what to be implemented with this kind of issue. I would be very thankful if someone would provide me some code template how to implement this!

Comment: are you trying to connect with any bluetooth module or other android mobile?

Comment: I am trying to connect with Raspberry Pi.

Comment: i've used HC-05 bluetooth module to connect android mobile and I'm able to send and receive data's from my app

Comment: Did you have the socket connection under a button?

Comment: yes I do have socket connection

Comment: Do you initiate the connection when pressed a button?

Comment: you can call the connect method whenever you want. it's not necessary to be under `onClick` of a button.

Comment: Yes I know that but even though I initiate the connection for instance inside the onCreate method, the result is the same.

Comment: ok please refer the following code

Comment: Thank you Praveen!

Comment: have you tried it? if not please try and see if it works. and notice me if it works. hope this will help you.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 1):

**To Connect**

```
BluetoothSocket socket;
Handler bt_handler;
int handlerState;
OutputStream outputStream;
InputStream inputStream;
ConnectedThread connectedThread;
BluetoothAdapter adapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
BluetoothDevice device=adapter.getRemoteDevice(mac_address);
UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
try {
     socket=device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
     socket.connect();
     outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
     inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
     connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
     connectedThread.start();
}catch(Exception e){
    /** Handle the exception here **/
}
```

**Thread**

```
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    int avilableBytes=0;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket){
        InputStream temp=null;
        try{
            temp=socket.getInputStream();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream=temp;
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            int bytes;
            while (true){
                try{
                    avilableBytes=inputStream.available();
                    byte[] buffer=new byte[avilableBytes];
                    if (avilableBytes>0){
                        bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                        final String readMessage=new String(buffer);
                        if (bytes>=3){
                            bt_handler.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                        }
                        else {
                            SystemClock.sleep(100);
                        }
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**bt_handler**

```
bt_handler=new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what==handlerState){
                String readMessage=(String)msg.obj;
                Log.v(TAG, readMessage);
            }
        }
```

define bt_handler inside onCreate()
`ConnectedThread` is inner class.